# Outside window sealant producing strong smell inside for 7+ days

Tags: sealant

Our apartment management put a clear sealant all around the windows - our windows as well as both up and down windows (from the other apartments), and around the boards surrounding the windows. In our one bedroom, the scent from the sealant was never smelled. In our daughter's bedroom, it has smelled terrible for a week.

Why does this smell so bad 7 days later? Is this toxic? It is permeating other surrounding rooms and is *not* helped with an air purifier. Opening the window makes the scent even stronger. It is a chemical scent and reminds me of paint thinner. We have tried setting out bowls of water, white vinegar, some baking soda and charcoal at different times. Nothing has helped.

The apartment people will not tell us what was used.

Answer (score 1):

Silicone and urethane caulks have solvents that can be quite caustic to the sinuses. All you can really do is ventilate well. It'll clear up with a little time, assuming good fresh air flow.

Answer (score 0):

It was probably something similar to Lexel sealant, which has a pronounced
solvent-like odor until completely cured, which can take a few days or more than a week depending on application volume. Some folks, including myself, like that scent.